Ordinals,set theory: Let $\gamma$ be continuous function with $\gamma(\alpha)\geq\alpha$ and $\gamma(\alpha)$ continuous. Why $\gamma(\alpha)=\alpha$?

Let $\gamma$ be continuous function with $\gamma(\alpha) \geq \alpha$
and $\gamma(\alpha)$ continuous. Why $\gamma(\alpha) = \alpha$ for arbitrarily large $\alpha$?

This is set theory. $\alpha$ is some ordinal. Thomas Jech concludes before his proof of Theorem 3.5(Set theory by Thomas Jech). Why is this? Reference: here(page 38)
Continuity of $\gamma(\alpha)$ means the limit of the sequence $\{\gamma(\eta) : \eta < \alpha\}$ is $\gamma(\alpha)$. Namely,
$$\gamma(\alpha) = \sup\{\gamma(\eta) : \eta < \alpha\}$$
The point $3$ in this post is well understood but I don't know why it implies that $\gamma(\alpha) = \alpha$ for "arbitrarily large $\alpha$"

Please fix the definition of continuity. It would imply that there is only one continuous function. Maybe you want a limit ordinal. Also, what do you mean precisely with "arbitrary large"?

I edited it. Please drop the downvote

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_lemma_for_normal_functions

@spaceisdarkgreen The book is truly for graduate. Okay. Thank you!

Let $\beta$ be a limit ordinal of uncountable cofinality and let $\gamma:\beta\rightarrow \beta$ be strictly increasing and continuous. We claim that $\{\alpha<\beta:\gamma(\alpha)=\alpha\}$ is unbounded.
First, by an easy transfinite induction, observe that $\gamma(\alpha)\geq\alpha$ for every $\alpha<\beta$: this is clear for $\alpha=0$. For the successor step, observe that $\gamma(\alpha+1)>\gamma(\alpha)\geq\alpha$, so $\gamma(\alpha+1)>\alpha$, thus $\gamma(\alpha+1)\geq\alpha+1$. For the limit step $\xi$, by continuity we have $\gamma(\xi)=\sup\{\gamma(\alpha):\alpha<\xi\}\geq\sup\{\alpha:\alpha<\xi\}=\xi$.
Now given $\alpha_0<\beta$, we show that there exists $\alpha>\alpha_0$ in $\beta$ such that $\gamma(\alpha)=\alpha$. We recursively define a strictly increasing sequence $\alpha_n$ for $n\in \omega$ starting with $\alpha_0$ such that $\alpha_{n+1}>\gamma(\alpha_n)$. This is easy: after defining $\alpha_n$, let  e.g. $\alpha_{n+1}=\gamma(\alpha_n)+1$, which is greater than $\alpha_n$.
Now let $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_n: n \in \omega\}$. As $\alpha\geq\alpha_1>\alpha_0$ and the cofinality of $\beta$ is uncountable, we have $\alpha_0<\alpha<\beta$. As $\alpha_n$ is strictly increasing, its supremum $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. We claim that $\gamma(\alpha)=\alpha$:
$\geq$: we already know that $\gamma(\alpha)\geq \alpha$.
$\leq$: by continuity, $\gamma(\alpha)=\sup\{\gamma(\delta):\delta<\alpha\}$. Given $\delta<\alpha$, there exists $n\in \omega$ such that $\delta<\alpha_n$ (by the definition of $\alpha$) so $\alpha\geq\alpha_{n+1}>\gamma(\alpha_n)>\gamma(\delta)$ which shows that $\alpha$ is an upper bound of ${\gamma(\delta):\delta<\alpha}$.

That's kinda over-kill but fine. Thank you!

@MathInquirer why exactly do you feel like this is overkill?
